# Como criar foreach (PHP/SQL)

Tags: php, sql, foreach

Estou tentando enviar de um `form` em html, uma tabela, com dois campos com `Array[]`. Estes dois campos são Serviço e Valor, quero adicionar mais de um produto no `form`, e ele inserir em diferentes registros na minha tabela.

Fiz assim: duplico os campos em javascript, e envio tudo junto por POST.

```
  <input name="valor[]" type="text" id="valor[]" size="6">
```

No SQL, estou fazendo assim:

```
$carro=strtoupper($_POST['carro']);
$placa=strtoupper($_POST['placa']);
$cor=strtoupper($_POST['cor']);
$hora=strtoupper($_POST['hora']);
$proprietario=$_POST['proprietario'];

$i = 0;

 foreach($_POST["servico"] as $id => $servico);
 foreach($_POST["valor"] as $id => $valor);

$telefone=strtoupper($_POST['telefone']);
$buscar=strtoupper($_POST['buscar']);
$obs=strtoupper($_POST['obs']);
$data=strtoupper($_POST['data']);
$ativo=strtoupper($_POST['ativo']);

   {
mysql_query("INSERT INTO agenda (carro, placa, cor, hora, proprietario, servico, valor, telefone, buscar, obs, data, ativo) VALUES ('$carro', '$placa', '$cor', '$hora', '$proprietario', '{$_POST['servico'][$i]}', '{$_POST['valor'][$i]}', '$telefone', '$buscar', '$obs', '$data', 'SIM')");

    ++$i;
        };


$i = 0;
```

Porem, ele salva apenas a primeira linha. Os campos duplicados, é ignorado.

Podem me dar uma luz ai?

Agradeço desde já ;)

Comment: Não sei pq os foreachs estão alinhados ... quando vc coloca um `;` no foreach ele morre ali mesmo, nessas situações use um bloco delimitado  `{` e `}` e não use funções obsoletas.

Comment: não funcionou :/

Comment: As chaves foram só uma dica, vc precisa explicar pq os foreach estão alinhados, aquele `$i` também não faz muito sentido. Você precisa explicar qual é o objetivo desse código.

Answer (score 1):

Bem o problema é que você esta fazendo de forma errada seus "for's" seja com o ";" matatando ele como o comemntario seja querendo correr 2x, o correto é apenas percorrer apenas uma matriz seja o "valor" ou seja o "servico" e a partir da chave dela fazer a inserção dos dados; Outro erro é que você esta misturando os dados do formuatio pois uma parte pelo que da pra percerber é matriz e a outra parte não é.

Mas vamos a um exemplo mais prático ... primeiro o HTML que acredito que não possua dúvidas...

**HTML**

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>" method="post">
<!-- Outros campos do seu Formulátrio -->

Serviço/Valor #1:<br>
<input name="servico[]" type="text" id="servico[]" size="10">
<input name="valor[]" type="text" id="valor[]" size="6"><br>

Serviço/Valor #2:<br>
<input name="servico[]" type="text" id="servico[]" size="10">
<input name="valor[]" type="text" id="valor[]" size="6"><br>

Serviço/Valor #3:<br>
<input name="servico[]" type="text" id="servico[]" size="10">
<input name="valor[]" type="text" id="valor[]" size="6"><br><br> 

<input type="submit">
</form>
```

E a parte que importa o PHP em sí ... eu só estou ponto a parte que importa que é o `foreach` o resto acho que da já sabe o que faz...

**PHP**

```
<?php
/* Campos do formulario */
$carro = strtoupper($_POST["carro"]);
$placa = strtoupper($_POST["placa"]);
$cor   = strtoupper($_POST["cor"]);
/* Seus outros campos entra aqui */

// Faz a 'leitura' de todos os campos serviço
// Trazendo sua posição (key) e valor 
foreach ($_POST["servico"] as $chave => $valor) {
 $dados_servico = $valor; // Adiciona o valor a variável apenas visual
 $dados_valor = $_POST["valor"][$chave]; // Com a chave pega a mesma posição porem do campo "valor" 

 // Insere no Banco
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO agenda (carro, placa, cor, hora, proprietario, servico, valor, telefone, buscar, obs, data, ativo) VALUES ('$carro', '$placa', '$cor', '$hora', '$proprietario', '$dados_servico', '$dados_valor', '$telefone', '$buscar', '$obs', '$data', 'SIM')");  
}   
?>
```

Comment: Deu tudo certo ;) Obrigado